# How to print 'fieldnames' using python csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file that I want to work with and the column heading may change over time.  The first thing I want to do is see the field names.  I can see the `csvreader.fieldnames` object in the documentation [[link]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), but I can't find any examples.

What's the simplest way to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `csv.DictReader` when you already know the columns that the CSV file will have.

If you don't know that then you could consider reading the first line with `csv.reader` to obtain the names of the columns and then read the file again with a `csv.DictReader` (which can then be instantiated with the right `fieldnames`).

Comment: How would the code look to use csv.reader and then csv.DictReader?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,

```
with open('yourFile.csv', "rt", newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,
                               delimiter=',',
                               quotechar='|')
return csvreader.fieldnames
```